# how to use memcpy in 3d arrays in C

Tags: c

I have a 3 dimensional array `int32_t x[1024][4][256]`. I need to copy all the elements of the array to another array of same type and size `int32_t y[1024][4][256]`.

Can i use `memcpy(y, x, sizeof(x));`?

after that can I access the elements of array `y` same as that of `x`?

Answer (score 11):

> can i use `memcpy(y, x, sizeof(x))`?

Yes.

> after that can I access the elements of array `y` same as that of `x`?

Yes.

Note that this approach breaks down if you allocate the array dynamically (e.g. using `malloc()`). If you do that, `sizeof()` will no longer give you the size of the array (it will give the size of the pointer), and you'll have to keep track of the array dimensions yourself.

Comment: ok, Thanks, I read some where that the arrays in C are contiguous elements, so memcpy works to copy all the elements of the array. So is it never depended on the number of dimensions of the array? can I use it to any number of dimensional array in C, provided I'm not using malloc and independently declaring the variables as above, like int32_t x[128][256][1024]..?

Comment: Yes, a multi-dimensional array is just an array of arrays.

Comment: @user1390048: Yes you can. The number of dimensions does not matter.

Comment: Note: this is safe in C, *not* in C++. I know @user1390048 tagged the question as C only, but it's worth mentioning just in case somebody wants to try it in C++.

Comment: Can you briefly telly me why is it not safe in c++??

Comment: @Jonathan: What exactly is not safe about this in C++?  Do you have a citation?  It might be preferable in certain situations to use a `std::vector` instead of a C array, but that doesn't make using a C array wrong or unsafe.

Comment: `memcpy()` is only safe in C++ with POD types (which `int32_t` is, of course.) Because more complex types cannot be copied this way, you must use an alternate approach such as `std::copy()` to do the work. If one wants to code consistently and cleanly, always using `std::copy()` would help prevent accidental misuse of `memcpy()`.